# Definition of star shaped domain

Tags: complex-analysis

This is from Gamelin's complex analysis text.

[image]

In this parargraph, the slit plane $C\setminus (-\infty,0]$ is star shaped with respect to only points on the positive real axis. Now the following paragraph states:

[image]

So if $C\setminus (-\infty,0]$ is a star shaped domain, then it is star shaped with respect to any one of its points which the previous paragraph clearly said is not the case. So I would like to ask is this a mistake by the author?

Comment: Where do you think the mistake is? The two paragraphs do not contradict each other.

Comment: It's star shaped wrt $1$. $1$ is one of its points. So it's star shaped wrt one of its points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second paragraph says "... star-shaped with respect to one of its points"; i.e there must exist a point belonging to that set with respect to which the set is star-shaped. The definition does not require it to be star-shaped with respect to every point.